# Disable all Facebook apps posted on my wall

Tags: facebook

How can I disable the Facebook apps that appear on my wall all in one go?

I can disable applications individually on my wall (the applications that my friends posted), but how can I disable them all?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no way to disable them all at once. You can, however, block all invites coming from a person, so if there's one person sending all the app invites, you can add the person to the blocked app invites list available in [Privacy Settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=privacy&section=block).

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To disable all Apps in Facebook you can go to:

- `Privacy Settings`
- Under `Apps and websites` click the `Edit Settings` link
- Under the list of **Apps you use** click the link `Turn off all apps`